# Reconstructing a full image from batched segments

Tags: python, tensorflow

Because my input images are too large to compute in my neural network, they have been split into small patches using `extract_image_patches`. The patches are then batched together before being input into the network. Currently, there are 256 patches in each batch, but each image is split into 1024 patches in total, meaning 4 batches would need to be read to reconstruct the image.

For reconstruction, I am using the following code:

```
image = tf.image.decode_png(...)
...
patch_size = [1, 32, 32, 1]
patches = tf.extract_image_patches([image],
    patch_size, patch_size, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')
patches = tf.reshape(patches, [1024, 32, 32, 3])
...
reconstructed = tf.reshape(patches, [1, 1024, 1024, 3])
encoded = tf.image.encode_png(reconstructed[0])
```

This works until batching is involved (unless the number of batches is 1024):

```
patch_batch = tf.train.batch([patches],
        batch_size=256,
        enqueue_many=True,
        capacity=capacity)

reconstructed = tf.reshape(patch_batch, [1, 1024, 1024, 3]) <-- fails
```

At first, I tried to use a FIFOQueue, but this will hang indefinitely as the buffer cannot accumulate enough data before a dequeue is requested:

```
buf = tf.FIFOQueue(1024, dtypes=[tf.uint8], shapes=[[32, 32, 3]])
buf.enqueue_many(patch_batch)
all_patches = buf.dequeue_many(1024)

reconstructed = tf.reshape(all_patches, [1, 1024, 1024, 3])
```

What's the correct way of 'unbatching' this data?

Comment: Is it hanging because of dequeuing so many patches (1024) ?? Did you try with different capacities of FIFOQueue and dequeue_many ?? If yes, is it working with smaller sizes ?

Comment: I think it's hanging because dequeue will block until the correct number of tensors are available, which won't happen until enqueue has been executed 4 times. What I really need is for dequeue to return something like None if the queue isn't full yet.

Comment: I think the solution is just the batch the data again with a new batch size of 1024. Is this a good idea?

Comment: I answered this question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047753/reconstructing-an-image-after-using-extract-image-patches/44052227#44052227