# Reconstructing an image after using extract_image_patches

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an autoencoder that takes an image as an input and produces a new image as an output.

The input image (1x1024x1024x3) is split into patches (1024x32x32x3) before being fed to the network.

Once I have the output, also a batch of patches size 1024x32x32x3, I want to be able to reconstruct a 1024x1024x3 image. I thought I had this sussed by simply reshaping, but here's what happened.

First, the image as read by Tensorflow:
[image: Input image]

I patched the image with the following code

```
patch_size = [1, 32, 32, 1]
patches = tf.extract_image_patches([image],
    patch_size, patch_size, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')
patches = tf.reshape(patches, [1024, 32, 32, 3])
```

Here are a couple of patches from this image:

[image: Patched input #168] [image: Patched input #169]

But it's when I reshape this patch data back into an image that things go pear-shaped.

```
reconstructed = tf.reshape(patches, [1, 1024, 1024, 3])
converted = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(reconstructed, tf.uint8)
encoded = tf.image.encode_png(converted)
```

[image: Reconstructed output]

In this example, no processing has been done between patching and reconstructing. I have made a [version of the code](https://pastebin.com/vPyRGcQG) you can use to test this behaviour. To use it, run the following:

```
echo "/path/to/test-image.png" > inputs.txt
mkdir images
python3 image_test.py inputs.txt images
```

The code will make one input image, one patch image, and one output image for each of the 1024 patches in each input image, so comment out the lines that create input and output images if you're only concerned with saving all the patches.

Somebody, please explain what happened :(

Comment: CJxD, have a look at my answer. You can print patches and reconstructed in 1st part to see the mistake happening in your code.  I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: "that things go pear-shaped". I'm going to borrow that expression!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **Update#2** - One small example for your task: (TF 1.0)

Considering image of size (4,4,1) converted to patches of size (4,2,2,1) and reconstructed them back to image.

```
import tensorflow as tf
image = tf.constant([[[1],   [2],  [3],  [4]],
                 [[5],   [6],  [7],  [8]],
                 [[9],  [10], [11],  [12]],
                [[13], [14], [15],  [16]]])

patch_size = [1,2,2,1]
patches = tf.extract_image_patches([image],
    patch_size, patch_size, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')
patches = tf.reshape(patches, [4, 2, 2, 1])
reconstructed = tf.reshape(patches, [1, 4, 4, 1])
rec_new = tf.space_to_depth(reconstructed,2)
rec_new = tf.reshape(rec_new,[4,4,1])

sess = tf.Session()
I,P,R_n = sess.run([image,patches,rec_new])
print(I)
print(I.shape)
print(P.shape)
print(R_n)
print(R_n.shape)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]]
  [[ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8]]
  [[ 9][10][11][12]]
  [[13][14][15][16]]]
(4, 4, 1)
(4, 2, 2, 1)
[[[ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]]
  [[ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8]]
  [[ 9][10][11][12]]
  [[13][14][15][16]]]
(4,4,1)
```

#Update - for 3 channels (debugging..)
working only for p = sqrt(h)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
c = 3
h = 1024
p = 32

image = tf.random_normal([h,h,c])
patch_size = [1,p,p,1]
patches = tf.extract_image_patches([image],
   patch_size, patch_size, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')
patches = tf.reshape(patches, [h, p, p, c])
reconstructed = tf.reshape(patches, [1, h, h, c])
rec_new = tf.space_to_depth(reconstructed,p)
rec_new = tf.reshape(rec_new,[h,h,c])

sess = tf.Session()
I,P,R_n = sess.run([image,patches,rec_new])
print(I.shape)
print(P.shape)
print(R_n.shape)
err = np.sum((R_n-I)**2)
print(err)
```

Output :

```
(1024, 1024, 3)
(1024, 32, 32, 3)
(1024, 1024, 3)
0.0
```

#Update 2

Reconstructing from the output of extract_image_patches seems difficult. Used other functions to extract patches and reverse the process to reconstruct which seems easier.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
c = 3
h = 1024
p = 128


image = tf.random_normal([1,h,h,c])

# Image to Patches Conversion
pad = [[0,0],[0,0]]
patches = tf.space_to_batch_nd(image,[p,p],pad)
patches = tf.split(patches,p*p,0)
patches = tf.stack(patches,3)
patches = tf.reshape(patches,[(h/p)**2,p,p,c])

# Do processing on patches
# Using patches here to reconstruct
patches_proc = tf.reshape(patches,[1,h/p,h/p,p*p,c])
patches_proc = tf.split(patches_proc,p*p,3)
patches_proc = tf.stack(patches_proc,axis=0)
patches_proc = tf.reshape(patches_proc,[p*p,h/p,h/p,c])

reconstructed = tf.batch_to_space_nd(patches_proc,[p, p],pad)

sess = tf.Session()
I,P,R_n = sess.run([image,patches,reconstructed])
print(I.shape)
print(P.shape)
print(R_n.shape)
err = np.sum((R_n-I)**2)
print(err)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1024, 1024, 3)
(64, 128, 128, 3)
(1, 1024, 1024, 3)
0.0
```

You could see other cool tensor transformation functions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops

Comment: your 2nd example crashes if I set different patch size. p = 64 for example

Comment: You gotta adjust "h" while reshaping patches. Will update it now.

Comment: It crashes even if you set `tf.reshape(patches, [(h/p)**2, p, p, c])`

Comment: Its not crashing for me. But giving wrong output. Let me debug it for various sizes.

Comment: @Temak, Hey, would you please check my update2 ?? let me know if there is any issue. Thanks.

Comment: Your update #2 works well for me. I've cleaned it up and generalised it for any patch size (such as 32x64) https://pastebin.com/mLUP8mgU

Answer (score 11):

Since I also struggled with this, I post a solution that might be useful to others. The trick is to realize that the inverse of `tf.extract_image_patches` is its gradient, as [suggested here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6743#issuecomment-271969125). Since the gradient of this op is implemented in Tensorflow, it is easy to build the reconstruction function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def extract_patches(x):
    return tf.extract_image_patches(
        x,
        (1, 3, 3, 1),
        (1, 1, 1, 1),
        (1, 1, 1, 1),
        padding="VALID"
    )

def extract_patches_inverse(x, y):
    _x = tf.zeros_like(x)
    _y = extract_patches(_x)
    grad = tf.gradients(_y, _x)[0]
    # Divide by grad, to "average" together the overlapping patches
    # otherwise they would simply sum up
    return tf.gradients(_y, _x, grad_ys=y)[0] / grad

# Generate 10 fake images, last dimension can be different than 3
images = np.random.random((10, 28, 28, 3)).astype(np.float32)
# Extract patches
patches = extract_patches(images)
# Reconstruct image
# Notice that original images are only passed to infer the right shape
images_reconstructed = extract_patches_inverse(images, patches) 

# Compare with original (evaluating tf.Tensor into a numpy array)
# Here using Keras session
images_r = images_reconstructed.eval(session=K.get_session())

print (np.sum(np.square(images - images_r))) 
# 2.3820458e-11
```

Comment: Your code did not work for me. On execution it gives the following error 
``
ValueError: Operation 'ExtractImagePatches_1' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'.
 rows_out = int(ceil((rows_in - ksize_r_eff + 1) / stride_r))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
``

Comment: Maybe a version of Tensorflow that does not support some of the operations? The exact code above (now also with import(s) statements) works for me on Tensorflow 1.7.0 and Keras 2.2.0. Are you running exactly that code or adapting it?

Comment: Marco, thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: How would you do this in TF2.0+? I'm getting 
`RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.` 
Can't get it to work with `tf.GradientTape()` so far.

Comment: @c_student Here's a gist with code for TF2+, not very efficient though: https://gist.github.com/hwaxxer/17ea565f86b748ba9471546b2532d0cf

Comment: This can work just fine in TF2+ by wrapping the inverse function in tf.function. Here is a full example: https://gist.github.com/aewhite/14db960f9e832bce4041bf185cdc9615

Answer (score 4):

`tf.extract_image_patches` is quite difficult to use, as it does a lot of stuff in the background.

If you just need non-overlapping, then it's much easier to write it ourselves.
You can reconstruct the full image by inverting all operations in `image_to_patches`.

**Code sample (plots original image and patches):**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def image_to_patches(image, patch_height, patch_width):
    # resize image so that it's dimensions are dividable by patch_height and patch_width
    image_height = tf.cast(tf.shape(image)[0], dtype=tf.float32)
    image_width = tf.cast(tf.shape(image)[1], dtype=tf.float32)
    height = tf.cast(tf.ceil(image_height / patch_height) * patch_height, dtype=tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(tf.ceil(image_width / patch_width) * patch_width, dtype=tf.int32)

    num_rows = height // patch_height
    num_cols = width // patch_width
    # make zero-padding
    image = tf.squeeze(tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, height, width))

    # get slices along the 0-th axis
    image = tf.reshape(image, [num_rows, patch_height, width, -1])
    # h/patch_h, w, patch_h, c
    image = tf.transpose(image, [0, 2, 1, 3])
    # get slices along the 1-st axis
    # h/patch_h, w/patch_w, patch_w,patch_h, c
    image = tf.reshape(image, [num_rows, num_cols, patch_width, patch_height, -1])
    # num_patches, patch_w, patch_h, c
    image = tf.reshape(image, [num_rows * num_cols, patch_width, patch_height, -1])
    # num_patches, patch_h, patch_w, c
    return tf.transpose(image, [0, 2, 1, 3])


image = io.imread('http://www.petful.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/slow-blinking-cat.jpg')
print('Original image shape:', image.shape)
tile_size = 200
image = tf.constant(image)
tiles = image_to_patches(image, tile_size, tile_size)

sess = tf.Session()
I, tiles = sess.run([image, tiles])
print(I.shape)
print(tiles.shape)


plt.figure(figsize=(1 * (4 + 1), 5))
plt.subplot(5, 1, 1)
plt.imshow(I)
plt.title('original')
plt.axis('off')
for i, tile in enumerate(tiles):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, 5 + 1 + i)
    plt.imshow(tile)
    plt.title(str(i))
    plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the following code is an efficient implementation but it works!

```
_,n_row,n_col,n_channel = x.shape
n_patch = n_row*n_col // (patch_size**2) #assume square patch

patches = tf.image.extract_patches(image,sizes=[1,patch_size,patch_size,1],strides=[1,patch_size,patch_size,1],rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],padding='VALID')
patches = tf.reshape(patches,[n_patch,patch_size,patch_size,n_channel])

rows = tf.split(patches,n_col//patch_size,axis=0)
rows = [tf.concat(tf.unstack(x),axis=1) for x in rows] 

reconstructed = tf.concat(rows,axis=0)
```

Comment: reminder that you can also do patches = tf.reshape(patches,[-1,patch_size,patch_size,n_channel]) when patches are evenly divisible in case you can't compute number of patches easily.

Comment: It seems to work for rectangular patches also, if we specify the number of rows properly for number of splits.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for your specific case, as well as for cases when the images are square, with a square kernel and the image size is divisible by the kernel size.

I did not test it for other cases.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


size = 1024
k_size = 32
axes_1_2_size = int(np.sqrt((size * size) / (k_size * k_size)))

# Define a placeholder for image (or load it directly if you prefer) 
img = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(1, size, size, 3))

# Extract patches
patches = tf.image.extract_image_patches(img, ksizes=[1, k_size, k_size, 1], 
                                         strides=[1, k_size, k_size, 1], 
                                         rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')

# Reconstruct the image back from the patches
# First separate out the channel dimension
reconstruct = tf.reshape(patches, (1, axes_1_2_size, axes_1_2_size, k_size, k_size, 3)) 
# Tranpose the axes (I got this axes tuple for transpose via experimentation)
reconstruct = tf.transpose(reconstruct, (0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5))
# Reshape back
reconstruct = tf.reshape(reconstruct, (size, size, 3))

im_arr = # load image with shape (size, size, 3)

# Run the operations
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ps, r = sess.run([patches, reconstruct], feed_dict={img:[im_arr]})

# Plot the reconstructed image to verify
plt.imshow(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tf 2.0 users can use  space_to_depth and depth_to_space if you aren't doing overlapping blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit late, but since I got it working with `TF-2.3`, it might prove useful for others. The following code works for non-overlapping patches - single or multi-channel:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class PatchesToImage(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, imgh, imgw, imgc, patsz, is_squeeze=True, **kwargs):
        super(PatchesToImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.H = (imgh // patsz) * patsz
        self.W = (imgw // patsz) * patsz
        self.C = imgc
        self.P = patsz
        self.is_squeeze = is_squeeze
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        bs = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        rows, cols = self.H // self.P, self.W // self.P
        patches = tf.reshape(inputs, [bs, rows, cols, -1, self.C])
        pats_by_clist = tf.unstack(patches, axis=-1)
        def tile_patches(ii):
            pats = pats_by_clist[ii]
            img = tf.nn.depth_to_space(pats, self.P)
            return img 
        img = tf.map_fn(fn=tile_patches, elems=tf.range(self.C), fn_output_signature=inputs.dtype)
        img = tf.squeeze(img, axis=-1)
        img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1,2,3,0])
        C = tf.shape(img)[-1]
        img = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.constant(self.is_squeeze), C==1), 
                      lambda: tf.squeeze(img, axis=-1), lambda: img)
        return img
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically address the initial question, which is 'Reconstructing an image after using extract_image_patches', I propose using `tf.scatter_nd()` and building a stratified image. This will work even in a situation where there is an overlap in the extracted patches or the image is under-sample. Here is my proposed solution.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Function to extract patches using 'extract_image_patches'
def img_to_patches(raw_input, _patch_size=(128, 128), _stride=100):

    with tf.variable_scope('im2_patches'):
        patches = tf.image.extract_image_patches(
            images=raw_input,
            ksizes=[1, _patch_size[0], _patch_size[1], 1],
            strides=[1, _stride, _stride, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding='SAME'
        )

        h = tf.shape(patches)[1]
        w = tf.shape(patches)[2]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, (patches.shape[0], -1, _patch_size[0], _patch_size[1], 3))
    return patches, (h, w)


# Function to reconstruct image
def patches_to_img(update, _block_shape, _stride=100):
    with tf.variable_scope('patches2im'):
        _h = _block_shape[0]
        _w = _block_shape[1]

        bs = tf.shape(update)[0]  # batch size
        np = tf.shape(update)[1]  # number of patches
        ps_h = tf.shape(update)[2]  # patch height
        ps_w = tf.shape(update)[3]  # patch width
        col_ch = tf.shape(update)[4]  # Colour channel count

        wout = (_w - 1) * _stride + ps_w  # Recalculate output shape of "extract_image_patches" including padded pixels
        hout = (_h - 1) * _stride + ps_h  # Recalculate output shape of "extract_image_patches" including padded pixels

        x, y = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(ps_w), tf.range(ps_h))
        x = tf.reshape(x, (1, 1, ps_h, ps_w, 1, 1))
        y = tf.reshape(y, (1, 1, ps_h, ps_w, 1, 1))
        xstart, ystart = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(0, (wout - ps_w) + 1, _stride),
                                     tf.range(0, (hout - ps_h) + 1, _stride))

        bb = tf.zeros((1, np, ps_h, ps_w, col_ch, 1), dtype=tf.int32) + tf.reshape(tf.range(bs), (-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))  #  batch indices
        yy = tf.zeros((bs, 1, 1, 1, col_ch, 1), dtype=tf.int32) + y + tf.reshape(ystart, (1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1))  # y indices
        xx = tf.zeros((bs, 1, 1, 1, col_ch, 1), dtype=tf.int32) + x + tf.reshape(xstart, (1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1))  # x indices
        cc = tf.zeros((bs, np, ps_h, ps_w, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int32) + tf.reshape(tf.range(col_ch), (1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1))  # color indices
        dd = tf.zeros((bs, 1, ps_h, ps_w, col_ch, 1), dtype=tf.int32) + tf.reshape(tf.range(np), (1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1))  # shift indices

        idx = tf.concat([bb, yy, xx, cc, dd], -1)

        stratified_img = tf.scatter_nd(idx, update, (bs, hout, wout, col_ch, np))
        stratified_img = tf.transpose(stratified_img, (0, 4, 1, 2, 3))

        stratified_img_count = tf.scatter_nd(idx, tf.ones_like(update), (bs, hout, wout, col_ch, np))
        stratified_img_count = tf.transpose(stratified_img_count, (0, 4, 1, 2, 3))

        with tf.variable_scope("consolidate"):
            sum_stratified_img = tf.reduce_sum(stratified_img, axis=1)
            stratified_img_count = tf.reduce_sum(stratified_img_count, axis=1)
            reconstructed_img = tf.divide(sum_stratified_img, stratified_img_count)

        return reconstructed_img, stratified_img



if __name__ == "__main__":

    # load initial image
    image_org = cv2.imread('orig_img.jpg')
    # Add batch dimension
    image = np.expand_dims(image_org, axis=0)

    # set parameters
    patch_size = (228, 228)
    stride = 200

    input_img = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=image.shape, name="input_img")

    # Extract patches using "extract_image_patches()"
    extracted_patches, block_shape = img_to_patches(input_img, _patch_size=patch_size, _stride=stride)
    # block_shape is the number of patches extracted in the x and in the y dimension
    # extracted_patches.shape = (1, block_shape[0] * block_shape[1], patch_size[0], patch_size[1], 3)

    reconstructed_img, stratified_img = patches_to_img(extracted_patches, block_shape, stride)  # Reconstruct Image


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        ep, bs, ri, si = sess.run([extracted_patches, block_shape, reconstructed_img, stratified_img], feed_dict={input_img: image})
        # print(bs)
    si = si.astype(np.int32)

    # Show reconstructed image
    cv2.imshow('sd', ri[0, :, :, :].astype(np.float32) / 255)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Show stratified images
    for i in range(si.shape[1]):

        im_1 = si[0, i, :, :, :]
        cv2.imshow('sd', im_1.astype(np.float32)/255)
```

The above solution should work for batched images of arbirary color channel dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented using `im2col` and `col2im`:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ImPatch():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def save_image(self, img, N=None):
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.savefig(str(N))
        plt.clf()

    def get_indices(self, X_shape, HF, WF, stride, pad):
        # get input size
        m, n_C, n_H, n_W = X_shape

        # get output size
        out_h = int((n_H + 2 * pad - HF) / stride) + 1
        out_w = int((n_W + 2 * pad - WF) / stride) + 1
    
        # ----Compute matrix of index i----

        # Level 1 vector.
        level1 = np.repeat(np.arange(HF), WF)
        # Duplicate for the other channels.
        level1 = np.tile(level1, n_C)
        # Create a vector with an increase by 1 at each level.
        everyLevels = stride * np.repeat(np.arange(out_h), out_w)
        # Create matrix of index i at every levels for each channel.
        i = level1.reshape(-1, 1) + everyLevels.reshape(1, -1)

        # ----Compute matrix of index j----
        
        # Slide 1 vector.
        slide1 = np.tile(np.arange(WF), HF)
        # Duplicate for the other channels.
        slide1 = np.tile(slide1, n_C)
        # Create a vector with an increase by 1 at each slide.
        everySlides = stride * np.tile(np.arange(out_w), out_h)
        # Create matrix of index j at every slides for each channel.
        j = slide1.reshape(-1, 1) + everySlides.reshape(1, -1)

        # ----Compute matrix of index d----

        # This is to mark delimitation for each channel
        # during multi-dimensional arrays indexing.
        d = np.repeat(np.arange(n_C), HF * WF).reshape(-1, 1)

        return i, j, d

    def im2col(self, X, HF, WF, stride, pad):
        # Padding
        X_padded = np.pad(X, ((0,0), (0,0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad)), mode='constant')
        i, j, d = self.get_indices(X.shape, HF, WF, stride, pad)
        # Multi-dimensional arrays indexing.
        cols = X_padded[:, d, i, j]
        cols = np.concatenate(cols, axis=-1)
        return cols

    def col2im(self, col, X_shape, HF, WF, stride, pad):
        # Get input size
        N, D, H, W = X_shape
        # Add padding if needed.
        H_padded, W_padded = H + 2 * pad, W + 2 * pad
        X_padded = np.zeros((N, D, H_padded, W_padded))
        
        # Index matrices, necessary to transform our input image into a matrix. 
        i, j, d = self.get_indices(X_shape, HF, WF, stride, pad)
        # Retrieve batch dimension by spliting dX_col N times: (X, Y) => (N, X, Y)
        dX_col_reshaped = np.array(np.hsplit(col, N))
        # Reshape our matrix back to image.
        # slice(None) is used to produce the [::] effect which means "for every elements".
        np.add.at(X_padded, (slice(None), d, i, j), dX_col_reshaped)
        # Remove padding from new image if needed.
        if pad == 0:
            return X_padded
        elif type(pad) is int:
            return X_padded[pad:-pad, pad:-pad, :, :]

    
    def get_patches(self, x, HF, WF, stride, verbose=False):
        x_patches = tf.image.extract_patches(x, sizes=[1, HF, WF, 1], strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
        if verbose == True:
            print (x_patches.shape, 'x_patches shape')
        
        return x_patches


    def get_img(self, x_patches, x_shape, HF, WF, stride, verbose=False):
        x_patches_T = np.transpose(x_patches, (0, 3, 1, 2))
        x_col = self.im2col(X=x_patches_T, HF=1, WF=1, stride=1, pad=0)
        if verbose == True:
            print (x_col.shape, 'x_col shape')

        x_shape = (x_shape[0], x_shape[3], x_shape[1], x_shape[2])
        x_reconstruct = self.col2im(col=x_col, X_shape=x_shape, HF=HF, WF=WF, stride=stride, pad=0)
        x_reconstruct_T = np.transpose(x_reconstruct, (0, 2, 3, 1))
        if verbose == True:
            print (x_reconstruct.shape, 'x_reconstruct shape')
            print (x_reconstruct_T.shape, 'x_reconstruct_T shape')

        return x_reconstruct_T

    def test(self, x, HF, WF, stride, save=True, verbose=True):
        x_patches = self.get_patches(x, HF=HF, WF=WF, stride=stride, verbose=verbose)
        x_reconstruct = self.get_img(x_patches, x_shape=x.shape, HF=HF, WF=WF, stride=stride, verbose=verbose)

        if save == True:
            idx = np.random.randint(0, x.shape[0])
            self.save_image(img=x[idx].reshape(28, 28), N=0)
            self.save_image(img=x_reconstruct[idx].reshape(28, 28), N=1)

        return x_reconstruct

impatch = ImPatch()

(x, _), (_, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x = np.expand_dims(x[0:10], axis=-1)

HF, WF, stride = 4, 4, 4
impatch.test(x, HF=HF, WF=WF, stride=stride)
```

Comment: how are merging the overlapping pixels, ? for instance, can I use the median to calculate a single pixel value in the overlapping regions?