# Reconstruct Image from overlapping patches of image

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have used `tf.extract_image_patches()` to get a tensor of overlapping patches 
 from the image as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047753/reconstructing-an-image-after-using-extract-image-patches) link. The answer in the mentioned link suggests to use `tf.space_to_depth()` to reconstruct the image from overlapping patches. But the problem is that this does not give the desirable results in my case and upon researching I came to know that `tf.space_to_depth()` does not deal with the overlapping blocks. My code looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

c = 3
height = 3900
width = 6000
ksizes = [1, 150, 150, 1]
strides = [1, 75, 75, 1]

image = #image of shape [1, height, width, 3]

patches = tf.extract_image_patches(image, ksizes = ksizes, strides= strides, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'VALID')
patches = tf.reshape(patches, [-1, 150, 150, 3])

reconstructed = tf.reshape(patches, [1, height, width, 3])
rec_new = tf.space_to_depth(reconstructed,75)
rec_new = tf.reshape(rec_new,[height,width,3])
```

This gives me error:

> ---
>
> **InvalidArgumentError**                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py
>   in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
>   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
>       653           graph_def_version, node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors,
>   --> 654           input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
>       655   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\contextlib.py in **exit**(self, type, value,
>   traceback)
>        87             try:
>   ---> 88                 next(self.gen)
>        89             except StopIteration:
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py
>   in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
>       465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
>   --> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
>       467   finally:
>
> **InvalidArgumentError**: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by
>   70200000 but is 271957500 for 'Reshape_22' (op: 'Reshape') with input
>   shapes: [4029,150,150,3], [4] and with input tensors computed as
>   partial shapes: input[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047753/reconstructing-an-image-after-using-extract-image-patches) = [?,3900,6000,3].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> **ValueError**                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 reconstructed = tf.reshape(features, [-1, height, width, channel])
>         2 rec_new = tf.space_to_depth(reconstructed,75)
>         3 rec_new = tf.reshape(rec_new,[h,h,c])
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py
>   in reshape(tensor, shape, name)    2617   """    2618   result =
>   _op_def_lib.apply_op("Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape,
>   -> 2619                                 name=name)    2620   return result    2621
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py
>   in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
>       765         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
>       766                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
>   --> 767                          op_def=op_def)
>       768         if output_structure:
>       769           outputs = op.outputs
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs,
>   op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)    2630
>   original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)    2631     if
>   compute_shapes:
>   -> 2632       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)    2633     self._add_op(ret)    2634
>   self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   set_shapes_for_outputs(op)    1909       shape_func =
>   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op    1910 
>   -> 1911   shapes = shape_func(op)    1912   if shapes is None:    1913     raise RuntimeError(
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   call_with_requiring(op)    1859     1860   def
>   call_with_requiring(op):
>   -> 1861     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)    1862     1863   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op =
>   call_with_requiring
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py
>   in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn)
>       593     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
>       594                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
>   --> 595                                   require_shape_fn)
>       596     if not isinstance(res, dict):
>       597       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py
>   in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
>   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
>       657       missing_shape_fn = True
>       658     else:
>   --> 659       raise ValueError(err.message)
>       660 
>       661   if missing_shape_fn:
>
> **ValueError**: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 70200000 but is
>   271957500 for 'Reshape_22' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes:
>   [4029,150,150,3], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial
>   shapes: input[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047753/reconstructing-an-image-after-using-extract-image-patches) = [?,3900,6000,3].

I know this is error due to non-compatible dimensions, but it should be that way, right? Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that in the link you posted the author is using the same value for `strides` and `ksizes`, while you are using `strides` equal to one half of `ksizes`. This is the reason why the dimensions do not match, you should write the logic of reducing the size of the patches before gluing them (for instance by selecting the central square of each patch).

Comment: I do not understand, the documentation says that 'strides' will define the distance between center of patches and 'ksizes' is the size of filter and in result the size of each patch. Shouldn't it work in that way?

Comment: Indeed , in the link the author is using non overlapping patches. I  am looking also for a method to reconstruct from overlapping patches