# How do I know if a built-in TensorFlow function is differentiable?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I wish to know if there is any practical rule to know if a built-in function in TensorFlow is differentiable. For example:

```
from tf.operations.something import function

l1 = conv2d(input_data)
l1 = relu(l1)

l2 = function(l1)
l2 = conv2d(l2)
```

How do I know if I can train such a neural network? Will the gradients be propagated trough `function(.)`?

Comment: I will start with creating some optimizer, sending some data (e.g. random noise as images and labels), and checking what is returned by `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,var_list=variable_list)` for the variables from the layers which lie before `function()` call. Possible results can be: something, zero and NaN. Last two mean that there is no gradient. Also, thensorflow itself may say that op has no gradient defined.

Comment: @Slowpoke thanks for your answer. I had thought of that, too. However, I wonder if there is an attribute that says that a built-in function is differentiable. Maybe it belongs to some "collection"?

Comment: Perhaps this answer may give you what you want [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785735/1692060](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785735/1692060)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

1. coding the loss function
2. writing a custom training loop
3. Printing the gradients at each training step.