# Is there a function to compute the inverse of `tf.extract_volume_patches` for variable sized input?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I would like to compute the inverse of `tf.extract_volume_patches`. Using the gradients (as suggested in [#6743](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6743#issuecomment-271969125) and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785735/12528320)) to compute the inverse of `tf.extract_volume_patches` works for statically known input shapes, however it does returns an error when used with variably input shapes.

An minimal example for synthetic 3D MNIST dataset, (it works when `input=(28,28,28,1)` however I need the extraction on variable sized data input (large biomedical images)):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def gaussian(x, amp=1, mu=None, sig=None):
    """ Gaussian function over d dimensions of x
    """
    if mu is None:
        mu = np.zeros_like(x)
    if sig is None:
        sig = np.ones_like(x)
    return amp * np.exp(-np.sum(np.square(x - mu) / (2 * np.square(sig))))

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.


multiplier = np.zeros((28,), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(4):
    multiplier[13-i] = round(gaussian(i),2)
    multiplier[14+i] = round(gaussian(i),2)
print(multiplier)

x_train = np.einsum('bhw,d->bdhw', x_train, multiplier)[...,np.newaxis]


class ExtractPatches(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ksizes, strides, shape):
        super(ExtractPatches, self).__init__()
        self.ksizes = ksizes
        self.strides = strides
        self.shape = shape

    def call(self, inputs):
        patches = tf.extract_volume_patches(inputs,
                                        ksizes=self.ksizes,
                                        strides=self.strides,
                                        padding="VALID")
        return tf.reshape(patches, self.shape), tf.shape(inputs)

class CombinePatches(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ksizes, strides):
        super(CombinePatches, self).__init__()
        self.ksizes = ksizes
        self.strides = strides

    def call(self, patches, inputs):
        target_volume = tf.zeros_like(inputs)
        target_patches = tf.extract_volume_patches(
            target_volume,
            ksizes=self.ksizes,
            strides=self.strides,
            padding="VALID"
        )
        # Creates list of gradient mappings from patches to target shape
        # Patches without overlap get 1, elements that overlap receive 1 
        # times the number of overlaps.
        target_grad_mapping = tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume)[0]

        # Computes gradients again and dividing by grad, otherwise its just summed.
        return tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume, patches)[0] / target_grad_mapping


def create_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,None,None,1))
    patches, shape = ExtractPatches(ksizes=[1,14,14,14,1], strides=[1,14,14,14,1], shape=(-1,14,14,14,1))(inputs)
    encoded = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=28, kernel_size=(14,14,14), strides=(14,14,14))(patches)
    decoded = tf.keras.layers.Conv3DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(14,14,14), strides=(14,14,14))(encoded)
    merged = CombinePatches(ksizes=[1,14,14,14,1], strides=[1,14,14,14,1])(decoded, inputs)

    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=merged)

ae = create_model()

ae.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
           loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
           metrics=['accuracy'])


test_history = ae.fit(x_train,
                       x_train,
                       batch_size=1,
                       epochs=1,
                       callbacks=None)
```

### Stacktrace

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-733ae79232be> in <module>()
     55 
     56 
---> 57 ae = create_model()
     58 
     59 ae.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 670           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    671         else:
    672           raise

TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-5-733ae79232be>:41 call  *
        target_grad_mapping = tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume)[0]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:318 gradients_v2  **
        unconnected_gradients)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:684 _GradientsHelper
        lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:340 _MaybeCompile
        return grad_fn()  # Exit early
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:684 <lambda>
        lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py:1067 _ExtractVolumePatchesGrad
        input_indices_num = 1 + planes_in * rows_in * cols_in

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing class `CombinePatches` call method

```py
target_grad_mapping = tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume)[0]

# Computes gradients again and dividing by grad, otherwise its just summed.
return tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume, patches)[0] / target_grad_mapping
```

to

```py
if target_patches.shape[0] is not None:
    target_grad_mapping = tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume)[0]

    # Computes gradients again and dividing by grad, otherwise its just summed.
    return tf.gradients(target_patches, target_volume, patches)[0] / target_grad_mapping
return target_volume
```

did the trick.